# Como fazer inner join dentro do Auth no laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Na *migration* padrão que o Laravel traz para utilizar o `Auth`, fiz uma *ForeignKey* com outra tabela ligando pelo ID. Para melhor entendimento coloco aqui as tabelas e com as seguintes colunas:

Plantas (tabela)

```
 ID | Nome (colunas)
```

Users (tabela criada pelo Auth)

```
ID | User | planta_id
```

Utilizando o método `{{ Auth::user()->planta_id }}` ele imprime o **id da tabela** plantas, queria usar o `INNER JOIN` para imprimir o `Nome` e não o `id`, porem não sei onde devo fazer isso.

Comment: você tem os models dessas duas tabelas e as relações prontas? se tiver o model pode colocar na pergunta?

Comment: tenho sim vou colocar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisa configurar os dois `models` com as relação de `1:N` (***1 para muitos***):

***Plantas***

```
class Plantas extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = "ID";
    protected $fillable = array('Nome');
    protected $table = "plantas";
    public $timestamps = false;
    public function users()
    {     
        return $this->hasMany('App\Users', 'planta_id', 'ID');
    }
}
```

***Users***

```
class Users extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = "ID";
    protected $fillable = array('Nome','planta_id');
    protected $table = "users";
    public $timestamps = false;
    public function planta()
    {     
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Plantas', 'planta_id', 'ID');
    }
}
```

Para pegar o ***nome*** da `planta`:

```
{{ Auth::user()->planta()->Nome }}
```

***Observação:*** coloque o nome dos campos em minúsculos e se for composto separado por `underscore`, nomenclatura padrão para desenvolvimento. Nada impede ser de outra forma, mas, fica mais legível em se tratando de [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) com [laravel-eloquent](/questions/tagged/laravel-eloquent)

*Eu não me atentei sobre o nomes dos campos, porque, ficou vago a parte do model `User`!*

**Link:** [One To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: É isso mesmo que eu queria, não sabia como teria que usar o hasMany nesse caso do Auth. Abriu minha mente, obrigado.

Comment: de *planta* para *user* é `hasMany` o contrário é `belongsTo` se atente a isso ...

Comment: Correto, você me ajudou muito, agora consigo me virar mais facilmente com a documentação https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many  muito obrigado.